# How to display self-joined tree hierarchy table by using BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, recursive-query, self-join

I am working on the tree hierarchy of supervisors and their supervised employees. The difficulty is that some supervisors are employees supervised by other supervisors, and there are lots of it.

For SQL queries I acquired from class, only about simple self-joins, which might be only like two levels: A is supervised by B, and that's it.

But the issue from the real world is far more complicated. There are multiple levels, and I am not sure about the exact number. For example, A is supervised by B, and B is supervised by C, and C is supervised by D, etc.

I assume there are only like 4 levels for supervision. 
The raw data might be like this:

```
         Employee     Supervisor
            A             B
            C             B
            D             B
            B             V
            E             V
            F             E
            G             V
            V          (Blank which indicates no boss)
```

And thus I generated the codes like below:

```
SELECT T1.Supervisor,ifnull(T2.EmployeeName, 'No Boss') as sup_emp1, 
ifnull(T3.EmployeeName, 'No Boss') as sup_emp2, ifnull(T4.EmployeeName, 
'No boss') as sup_emp3, ifnull(T5.EmployeeName, 'No Boss') as EMPLOYEE
FROM  T1
LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.Supervisor=T2.EmployeeName
LEFT JOIN  T3
ON T2.Supervisor = T3.EmployeeName
LEFT JOIN T4
ON T3.Supervisor = T4.EmployeeName
LEFT JOIN T5
ON T4.Supervisor = T5.EmployeeName
WHERE T5. Emp_Status = 'Active'
ORDER BY T1.Supervisor ASC
```

However, the results turned out to be wrong. I just got so confused about the tables the relationship and failed to think of the recursive joins.

The expected result should be like this:

```
Supervisor     # of Employees     
   V              7(include indirect supervised employees)
   B              3
   E              1
```

And the organization table should be:

```
Supervisor   Employee1    Employee2
   V             B             A
   V             B             C
   V             B             D
   V             E             F
   V             G            Null
```

But my result turned out to be

```
Supervisor   Employee1    Employee2
   V             B             A
   V             B             C
   V             B             D
   V             E             F
   V             V             G
```

<- I need the G to be on the second level.

So, can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... assume there are only like 4 levels for supervision ...

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and easily extended to more (reasonably more) levels just by adding more LEFT JOINs and respective fields into COALESCE

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t.Supervisor,
  IF(t.Supervisor = t5.Supervisor, 
    STRUCT(Employee2 AS Employee1, NULL AS Employee2),
    STRUCT(t5.Supervisor AS Employee1, Employee2 AS Employee2)
  ).*
FROM (
  SELECT t1.Employee Supervisor,
    COALESCE(t4.Employee, t3.Employee, t2.Employee) Employee2
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t1
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t2 ON t2.Supervisor = t1.Employee
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t3 ON t3.Supervisor = t2.Employee
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t4 ON t4.Supervisor = t3.Employee
  WHERE t1.Supervisor IS NULL
) t
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t5 ON t5.Employee = t.Employee2
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row Supervisor  Employee1   Employee2    
1   V           B           A    
2   V           B           C    
3   V           B           D    
4   V           E           F    
5   V           G           null
```

Comment: Sorry, sir. I am not familiar with Coalesce and Struct. Could you tell me how to edit it if I would like to have more than 2 employees? Like adding employee3 and 4?

Comment: OK. Thanks! Please look at my other question just posted.

Comment: sure. see my answer there

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT T1.Supervisor as BigBoss,
       T2.EmployeeName as level1, 
       T3.EmployeeName as level2,
       T4.EmployeeName as level3,
       T5.EmployeeName as level4
FROM T T1 LEFT JOIN
     T T2
     ON T1.Supervisor=T2.EmployeeName AND T2.Emp_Status = 'Active' LEFT JOIN 
     T T3
     ON T2.Supervisor = T3.EmployeeName AND T3.Emp_Status = 'Active' LEFT JOIN
     T T4
     ON T3.Supervisor = T4.EmployeeName AND T4.Emp_Status = 'Active' LEFT JOIN
     T T5
     ON T4.Supervisor = T5.EmployeeName AND T5.Emp_Status = 'Active'
WHERE T1.Emp_Status = 'Active' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM T ts
                  WHERE ts.EmployeeName = T1.SuperVisor
                 )
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ASC;
```

This starts with the big boss and then works its way down.

Comment: It cannot work on my part. It turned out to be only one record and all null.

Comment: @Sandy did you find a way to make it recursively?